# regex to match words ending in dtproj with dots

Tags: regex

What is the regex to select all words that have dot's in them or underscores and that end in .dtproj

for example I want both TY.zz.test.dtproj and DW.zan.da.man.dtproj from the below string ...

SccProjectUniqueName1 = TY.zz.test.dtproj

SccProjectUniqueName3 = DW.zan.da.man.dtproj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regex that matches a name with dots and ends with .dtproj

```regex
[\w.]+\.dtproj
```

Test [here](https://regex101.com/r/FfApAJ/1)

The `\w` captures letters, digits and also underscores.